# How can I set pattern like @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM")

Tags: jpa, nhibernate-mapping, spring-annotations, hibernate-entitymanager

I got issue about hibernate pojo annotation. One column in database is varchar with date pattern **yyyy-MM** (such as 2015-07, 2015-06), I **CAN NOT** change this varchar date pattern in database.

When I use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM")`, I got exception as

```
 ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Bad format for DATE '2015-05'
```

How can I get around this issue without changing varchar date pattern in database.

I made test in DB, with varchar pattern as (2015-07-01) and `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")`, **no exception throwed**. And I test pattern like (2015-May) with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MMM")`, **no exception throwed**. **Just when the pattern is in "yyyy-MM", it throws this exception.** Unfortunately, I must use this '2015-06' varchar pattern in database, how can I get around this issue, seems hibernate annotation not recognize this pattern as 'yyyy-MM'

I hope not using **AttributeConverter,** because I don't want build a new class for this problem, it might make my system even more messy.